# Checkbox generado por default en append manda valor equivocado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola les explico tengo un script que genera inputs de forma dinamica me funcionaba perfecto la deteccion de los checkbox con este codigo:

```
$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 'Si' : 'No';
    $(this).siblings('input.checkbox_handler').val(checkbox_val);
});
```

El problema era que por default no me mostraba ningún input así que agregue uno de forma estática, el problema es que ahora cuando marco el checkbox me manda un valor equivocado, si lo marco por ejemplo me da el valor contrario. Este es mi código completo:

```
<script>



$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");

     var selectproductos = "<?php $sql = "Select producto from productos"; $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['producto'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>";

            var selectunidades = "<?php $sql = "Select unidad from unidades";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['unidad'].'</option>';
       }
     ?> ";

          $(wrapper).children('table').append('<tr>   <td> <select required name="productos[]"><option value="">Selecciona un Producto</option>'+selectproductos+'</select><td><select required name ="unidad[]"><option value="">Selecciona una unidad</option>'+selectunidades+'</select></td><td><input type="text" class="inputancho" name="cantidad[]" placeholder="cantidad" required="required"/></td><td><input type="date"  name="fecha_de_embarque[]" required="required"/></td>  <td> <textarea  rows="2" cols="30" name="notas[]" id="notas" maxlength="255"></textarea> </td> <td>    <input type="hidden" class="checkbox_handler" name="etiquetado[]" value="No" /><input type="checkbox" name="etiquetado_ck[]" value="Si" />   </td><td><a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar</a></<td></tr>'); //add input box


    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
                var selectproductos = "<?php $sql = "Select producto from productos"; $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['producto'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>";

            var selectunidades = "<?php $sql = "Select unidad from unidades";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['unidad'].'</option>';
       }
     ?> ";




$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 'Si' : 'No';
    $(this).siblings('input.checkbox_handler').val(checkbox_val);
});

        }
  else
  {
  alert('You Reached the limits')
  }
    });

   $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); x--;
})



});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {

        $("#botonagregarproducto").click();

    }
});

    $(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 'Si' : 'No';
    $(this).siblings('input.checkbox_handler').val(checkbox_val);
});

$(document).trigger($.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));

</script>
```

Y asi hago el post:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   
                $id_cliente = $_POST['id_cliente'];
        $orden_de_compra = $_POST['orden_de_compra'];//funcionando


            $productos= (is_array($_POST['productos'])) ? $_POST['productos'] : array();
        $unidad= (is_array($_POST['unidad'])) ? $_POST['unidad'] : array();

            $cantidad= (is_array($_POST['cantidad'])) ? $_POST['cantidad'] : array();

            $fecha_de_embarque= (is_array($_POST['fecha_de_embarque'])) ? $_POST['fecha_de_embarque'] : array();

            $notas = (is_array($_POST['notas'])) ? $_POST['notas'] : array();
            $etiquetado= (is_array($_POST['etiquetado'])) ? $_POST['etiquetado'] : array();
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues el código necesario para recrear el error, para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Necesitaríamos algo de marcado html relevante para ver que puede estar pasando. Algún error en consola o semejante?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices *me manda un valor equivocado*, a que manda `Sí` cuando debe ser `No` y manda `No` cuando debe ser `Sí`? Si es eso, cambia el orden aquí: `var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 'Si' : 'No';`, o sea: **`var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 'No' : 'Si';`**

Comment: No me marca ningun error y lo que hace me lo hace solo si marco el checkbox me manda un valor de 'No' y si no lo marco si me manda el de no, repito en mi codigo original si me funciona a la perfeccion siempre y cuando no ponga un input por default, la idea es que el usuario entre y ya este uno creado, no que tenga que agregar el primero con enter o con el boton de agregar

Comment: Ya agregue como hago el post, ese es todo mi script

Answer (score 0):

Y si en vez de hacer el onChange en el $(document).on lo haces de esta manera

```
$("td input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
    var checkbox_val = $(this).prop('checked') ? 'Si' : 'No';
    $(this).siblings('input.checkbox_handler').val(checkbox_val);
});
```

Comment: No funciona lo puse fuera del document ready, se me hace complicado porque es un array de checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi escribiendo esto en seguida de mi inputs por default:

```
$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 'Si' : 'No';
    $(this).siblings('input.checkbox_handler').val(checkbox_val);
});
```

Y este es mi codigo completo ahora:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");

     var selectproductos = "<?php $sql = "Select producto from productos"; $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['producto'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>";

            var selectunidades = "<?php $sql = "Select unidad from unidades";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['unidad'].'</option>';
       }
     ?> ";

          $(wrapper).children('table').append('<tr>   <td> <select required name="productos[]"><option value="">Selecciona un Producto</option>'+selectproductos+'</select><td><select required name ="unidad[]"><option value="">Selecciona una unidad</option>'+selectunidades+'</select></td><td><input type="text" class="inputancho" name="cantidad[]" placeholder="cantidad" required="required"/></td><td><input type="date"  name="fecha_de_embarque[]" required="required"/></td>  <td> <textarea  rows="2" cols="30" name="notas[]" id="notas" maxlength="255"></textarea> </td> <td>    <input type="hidden" class="checkbox_handler" name="etiquetado[]" value="No" /><input type="checkbox" name="etiquetado_ck[]" value="Si" />   </td><td><a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar</a></<td></tr>'); //add input box

$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 'Si' : 'No';
    $(this).siblings('input.checkbox_handler').val(checkbox_val);
});


    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
                var selectproductos = "<?php $sql = "Select producto from productos"; $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['producto'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>";

            var selectunidades = "<?php $sql = "Select unidad from unidades";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['unidad'].'</option>';
       }
     ?> ";

          $(wrapper).children('table').append('<tr>   <td> <select required name="productos[]"><option value="">Selecciona un Producto</option>'+selectproductos+'</select><td><select required name ="unidad[]"><option value="">Selecciona una unidad</option>'+selectunidades+'</select></td><td><input type="text" class="inputancho" name="cantidad[]" placeholder="cantidad" required="required"/></td><td><input type="date"  name="fecha_de_embarque[]" required="required"/></td>  <td> <textarea  rows="2" cols="30" name="notas[]" id="notas" maxlength="255"></textarea> </td> <td>    <input type="hidden" class="checkbox_handler" name="etiquetado[]" value="No" /><input type="checkbox" name="etiquetado_ck[]" value="Si" />   </td><td><a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar</a></<td></tr>'); //add input box



$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 'Si' : 'No';
    $(this).siblings('input.checkbox_handler').val(checkbox_val);
});

        }
  else
  {
  alert('You Reached the limits')
  }
    });

   $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); x--;
})



});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {

        $("#botonagregarproducto").click();

    }
});

$(document).trigger($.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));

</script>
```